# Cronjob Unable to find ADB

Tags: bash, cron

I have a python program running on host and a cronjob setup to kill + update + restart every morning.

The python program itself uses ADB dependency on host. Whenever cron runs it can't find the binary:

/bin/sh: 1: adb: not found

I've done quite a bit of research here but not one solution I've tried made any change. Any ideas?

- Tried manually setting path in crontab

  ```
  which adb
  /home/<>/resources/AndroidTools/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb

  PATH=/home/<>/resources/AndroidTools/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
  ```
- Tried to manually load bashrc -and- bash_profile
- Tried multiple different edits to actual cron command by replacing /bin/sh or declaring path directly

  ```
  * * * * * bash -i python3 ~/.lab_inventory/inventory_driver.py &

  * * * * * /home/<>/resources/AndroidTools/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb python3 ~/.lab_inventory/inventory_driver.py &
  ```
- I even tried directly copy pasting the full PATH declaration existing in bashrc into crontab itself, no effect

Everytime still just get adb not found for ADB

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the cron tag states: Questions about configuring cron for systems or administration are OFF TOPIC.

Comment: I have no idea what you're implying but this is a project I use on multiple host to monitor ADB device status for viewing in a webtool. 'Systems and administration' seem like something you inferred on your own.

Comment: I am quoting the tag information so you know that your question is off topic:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron

Comment: And yet my question still has nothing to do with 'Systems' or 'administration'

Unless by 'System' you're referring to just any project in general, may as well close all tickets

Comment: Are you asking how to write a cron? If so, it's off topic.

Comment: See the [Learn More (about cron)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) info page. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute path of adb when invoking it

```
* * * * * /home/<>/resources/AndroidTools/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb devices
```

for example, or wherever you are using inside your script, perhaps

```
subprocess.run(['/home/<>/resources/AndroidTools/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb', 'devices')
```

BTW, PATH contains directories, not files, so you should remove `adb`

Comment: I can't use the absolute path in that way, as you can see I'm calling a script which is internally using ADB, not directly calling an ADB command.

I did try that format but with the script as command and even with full path there it still isn't found inside the script execution. I was thinking of forcing a local override here but the problem is cron job is created via setup script on multiple hosts. Much more efficient to change there then individually on each machine

Comment: We have to guess what's inside your `inventory_driver.py`...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this through a bit of a hack, the cron job script itself is setup via another full host setup script. In this script I grab the path via which adb and directly inject the path into cron job script.